# Sum two integers in JNI function return a wrong value

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am calling a native function that do a very simple summation operation, but it returns a wrong result why ?!

Here is my java code:

```
package com.example.sharedlibexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Value = " + String.valueOf(addInJNI(15, 8)));
    }

    public native int addInJNI(int a, int b);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
}
```

and this is the native code:

```
int Java_com_example_sharedlibexample_MainActivity_addInJNI(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The result of this sum example is:

```
-921636135
```

Comment: before adding a and b in JNI, you have to check whether are you getting correct values or not..??

Comment: @SarithaG I am just passing a constant values

Comment: Yah...but int may take different values in jni. once print those a and b value in console. or else use jint type instead of int.

Comment: @SarithaG using jint works for me .. thank you!

Comment: glad to help you..:)

Comment: Because you didn't follow the documentation and use the `javah` tool to generate the native method declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from this [blog](http://junedk.blogspot.in/2014/01/ndk-sum-of-two-values.html)
I could find the solution by using the `jint` rather than `int`

The solution is:

Create a header file bativeLib.h

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_marakana_NativeLib */

#ifndef _Included_org_example_ndk_nativeLib
#define _Included_org_example_ndk_nativeLib
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_marakana_NativeLib
 * Method:    add
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_sharedlibexample_MainActivity_addInJNI
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and the C lib looks like:

```
#include "nativeLib.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_sharedlibexample_MainActivity_addInJNI
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint value1, jint value2) {
        return (value1 + value2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The two first parameters in the native function should be `JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz` (or `JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz` for a static method). What your code current actually does, is that it adds the values of the `env` and `thiz` pointers, instead of the real parameters you intended to pass.

You can use `javah` to generate the method signatures (in the form of a header file), which also includes other attributes which may be necessary in some cases (like `JNIEXPORT`, `JNICALL`).